# Can I login to a site in batch?

Tags: batch-file, authentication, cmd

I want to make an program in batch that notiffies you about things that was posted on a site. But for posts to be shown, I need to login.
The program downloads the site using wget, then checks the HTML code for new information, but when I use wget to download the site, it downloads the login page from redirections. Is there a way to login to the site through CMD and then download the page shown before logining?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad language!

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication

Comment: I see that, but is for linux. I have Windows 7 x64 with wget 1.11.4. I found writing parameter --help that is a way with --http-user, but it still fails. Username contains "-" sign. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax should be the same for Windows/Linux

wget -m --http-user=username --http-password=password http://http.hostname.com/file

OR

wget -m http://username:password@hostname.com:/path/to/folder

P.S. - I dont think so, but maybe just give it a try by removing the "-"

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to use cookies, but I don't know how. More exactly, I need to login on a Moodle server. How can I do that?

Comment: I made it somehow. I copied Google Chrome cookie info to cookie file that is used to login to Moodle, but it resets after some tries...